# Сравнение 2 каталогов и подкаталогов в Bash

Tags: bash, sh

Задача такая : спавнить 2 каталога и подкаталога и выписать все , что у них разное. те. все то что есть только в 1 из каталогов(подкаталогов) или имею разное время измининия или размер.
Выписывать в виде :

<каталог1>:<локальный-адрес> <размер> <время измининия> <каталог2>:<лок.-адрес> <размер> <время изм.>

Пример

---

Для каталогов work , archiv

---

work:a.txt 1024 2010-09-10 10:20 archiv:

work:b.txt 20 2010-09-10 10:20 archiv:b.txt 25 2010-09-10 10:20

work:n.txt 100 2010-09-10 10:20 archiv:n.txt 100 2010-09-22 15:22

work: archiv:smt.data 256 2011-01-02 10:17

work: adr/smt.txt 256 2012-01-05 07:30 archiv:

---

Видел тут похожее

```
 #!/bin/bash
 ls $1 | while read i
 do
 if [ -e "$2/$i" ]
 then
 if [ `stat -c %Y $1/$i` -lt `stat -c %Y $2/$i` ] || [ `stat -c %s $1/$i` -lt `stat -c %s $2/$i` ]
 then echo ""
 else echo ""
 fi
 else
 echo "- $i (out of $2)"
 fi
 done

 ls $2 | while read i
 do
 if [ ! -e "$1/$i" ]
 then echo "+ $i ( out of $1)"
 fi
 done
```

но все еще не могу сравнить все что в одинаковых подкаталогах и правильно выписывать. Спасибо за любую помощь!

Comment: Не надо делать это на shell'е. Вот, например, на питоне это делается в несколько строк с помощью `os.walk()`.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте посмотреть в сторону утилит:

1. find (см. опцию -print),
2. diff,
3. grep или sed.

Comment: Это  пробовал , find ищет поимени , и выводит много предуприждений , так как я работаю с именем каталога /.../work/ или /archiv .
diff отсутсвует возможность правильного форматирования текста как в задании.

Comment: предупреждения в /dev/null можно отправить

Comment: для правильного форматирования использовать sed

Answer (score 1):

Сравнить 2 каталога и записать в файл разницу :

`diff -r dir1 dir2 | grep dir1 | awk '{print $4}' > difference1.txt`

Comment: а как насчет  <разимер> <время измининия> ?

Comment: С этой комманды я начитал . 
Вообще очень перспективно смотрелся приказ

       diff -y -r dir1 dir2

но нету нужного формата вывода.

Answer (score 0):

только сильно не пугайтесь

```
diff --brief -r /dir1/ /home/docker/dir2/ | grep Only |  sed 's,:,,g' | awk {'print $3$4'} | xargs ls -al

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 31 16:30 /dir1/ble.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar 31 16:32 /home/docker/dir2/bbb.log


comm -23 <(ls  /dir1 | sort) <(ls /home/docker/dir2 | sort)
ble.log
testdir
```

Answer (score 0):

Вот так решается эта поставленная задача

```
 #!/bin/bash
  ls -R $1 | while read i
 do
 if ! [[ $i == *":"* ]];
 then
 if ! [ -z $i ];
then
  if [ -e "$2/$i" ]
  then
    if [ `stat -c %Y $1/$i` -lt `stat -c %Y $2/$i` ] || [ `stat -c %s $1/$i`    -lt `stat -c %s $2/$i` ]
   then
     if ! [ -d $i ];
     then
     echo "$(basename $1): $(find $1 -name $i | sed "s_$1__" ) $(stat -c%s" "%z $1/$(find $1 -name $i | sed "s_$1__" ) | cut -d"." -f1) $(basename $2): $(find $2 -name $i | sed "s_$2__" ) $(stat -c%s" "%z $2/$(find $2 -name $i | sed "s_$2__" ) | cut -d"." -f1)"
     else
     echo "$(basename $1): $(find $1 -type d -name $i | sed "s_$1__" ) $(stat -c%s" "%z $1/$(find $1 -type d -name $i | sed "s_$1__" ) | cut -d"." -f1) $(basename $2): $(find $2 -type d -name $i | sed "s_$2__" ) $(stat -c%s" "%z $2/$(find $2 -name $i | sed "s_$2__" ) | cut -d"." -f1)"
     fi
   fi
else
     if ! [ -d $i ];
     then
     echo "$(basename $1): $(find $1 -name $i | sed "s_$1__" ) $(stat -c%s" "%z $1/$(find $1 -name $i | sed "s_$1__" ) | cut -d"." -f1) $(basename $2):"
     else
     echo "$(basename $1): $(find $1 -type d -name $i | sed "s_$1__" ) $(stat -c%s" "%z $1/$(find $1 -type d -name $i | sed "s_$1__" ) | cut -d"." -f1) $(basename $2):"
     fi
fi
fi
 fi
 done

ls -R $2 | while read i
do
 if ! [[ $i == *":"* ]];
 then
   if ! [ -z $i ];
 then
 if [ ! -e "$1/$i" ]
 then echo "$(basename $1): $(basename $2): $(find $2 -name $i | sed "s_$2__" ) $(stat -c%s" "%z $2/$(find $2 -name $i | sed "s_$2__" ) | cut -d"." -f1)"
 fi
 fi
  fi
 done
```

Пока решения лучше не нашел.